# What is the difference between ejs <%= and encodeURI for a JSON string result?

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, encode, ejs

So far according to my googling, `escape` was part of js and is deprecated and use encodeURI instead. But what about the `<%=` tag for ejs to escape variables? Are their effect is identical to a variable's JSON content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%=` escapes the data so it is suitable for inserting into an HTML document.

`encodeURI` escapes data so it is suitable for inserting into a URL.

They are completely different because they are targeting different output formats.